# Trim - Casing and Baseboard Installation

Tags: trim, baseboard

I want to install more decorative baseboard in my existing home. I currently have 2.5" plain casing and 4.5 inch plain baseboard. I have three windows that have 1/2 inch gap between the top of the baseboard and the bottom window casing. I now want to install more decorative casing and molding. I can trim down the casing molding to a little over 2.5 inches, but I would like to keep my 5 1/4 inch baseboard. Can the baseboard and casing touch? Can I reduce the baseboard just under the window and bring it base up to its original width of 5 1/4 inches on the left and right side of the window. Any ideas would be most appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would always run the baseboard consistently through a room.

So this suggests that you do something with the window casing. You could rip your window casing and have it touch the base... I don't think that would look terrible. Or (and I'm making assumptions that your window is cased 4 sides like a picture frame, here) you could install a stool/apron at the bottom of the windows and use a much smaller apron to give a bit of room between the base and the window.